# Viewpager fragment camera stretched

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-camera, android-fragmentactivity

For some weird reason the camera in the camerafragment is all stretched, it only appears when the theme is set to fullscreen/no action bar. Though my camera fragment has to be in fullscreen.
I have read some articles that your surfaceview should be equal to your camerapreview but when I change the resolution of the camerapreview the application crashes when entering the camerafragment.

Portrait camera:
[image: Portrait Picture]

Landscape camera:
[image: Landscape Picture]

The Camera fragment class:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Created by Gebruiker on 29-10-2014.
 */
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    View rootView;
    ImageButton cameraShootButton;
    ImageButton cameraChangeButton;
    ImageButton cameraFlitsButton;
    ImageButton timelineButton;
    ImageButton profileButton;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    Boolean switching = false;
    View.OnClickListener tapper = null;
    SurfaceView cameraPreview = null;
    SurfaceHolder cameraPreviewHolder = null;
    Camera camera = null;
    boolean inPreview = false;
    boolean cameraConfigured = false;
    Integer currentCamera;

    public static SecondFragment newInstance(String text) {

        SecondFragment f = new SecondFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag, container, false);

        timelineButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timelineB);
        profileButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profileB);

        cameraShootButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.captureB);
        cameraChangeButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.changeCameraB);
        cameraFlitsButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.flitserB);
        cameraPreview = (SurfaceView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cameraView);

        cameraPreviewHolder = cameraPreview.getHolder();
        cameraPreviewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
        cameraPreviewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        tapper = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.timelineB) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                } else if (v.getId() == R.id.captureB) {
                    camera.takePicture(ShutterCallback, PictureCallbackRaw, null, PictureCallbackJpeg);
                } else if(v.getId() == R.id.profileB){
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                } else if (v.getId() == R.id.changeCameraB) {
                    if (switching == true){
                        return;
                    }
                    changeCamera();
                } else if (v.getId() == R.id.flitserB){

                }
            }
        };

        cameraShootButton.setOnClickListener(tapper);
        cameraChangeButton.setOnClickListener(tapper);
        cameraFlitsButton.setOnClickListener(tapper);
        timelineButton.setOnClickListener(tapper);
        profileButton.setOnClickListener(tapper);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        camera = getCamera("back");
        currentCamera = 1;
        startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (inPreview) {
            camera.stopPreview();
        }
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        inPreview = false;

        super.onPause();
    }

    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
                                       Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result = null;

        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
                if (result == null) {
                    result = size;
                } else {
                    int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                    int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                    if (newArea > resultArea) {
                        result = size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (result);
    }

    private void initPreview(int width, int height) {
        if (camera != null && cameraPreviewHolder.getSurface() != null) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(cameraPreviewHolder);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
                        "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
            }

            if (!cameraConfigured) {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                Log.v("CAMERA", parameters.toString());
                Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(width, height,
                    parameters);

                if (size != null) {
                Log.v("CameraPreviewHeight", ""+cameraPreview.getMeasuredHeight());
                Log.v("CameraRES", size.width + " " + size.height);
                parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                cameraConfigured = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void startPreview() {
    if (cameraConfigured && camera != null) {
        camera.startPreview();
        inPreview = true;
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            camera.enableShutterSound(false);
        }
    }
}

private void changeCamera() {
    switching = true;
    if (inPreview) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    }
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    inPreview = false;
    if (currentCamera==1){
        camera = getCamera("front");
        currentCamera =2;
    }
    else{
        camera = getCamera("back");
        currentCamera = 1;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(cameraPreviewHolder);
        cameraPreviewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    inPreview = true;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        camera.enableShutterSound(false);
    }
    switching = false;

}

SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // no-op -- wait until surfaceChanged()
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        initPreview(width, height);
        startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // no-op
    }
};

Camera.ShutterCallback ShutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // no-op -- wait until surfaceChanged()
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        initPreview(width, height);
        startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // no-op
    }

    @Override
    public void onShutter() {

    }
};

Camera.PictureCallback PictureCallbackRaw = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // no-op -- wait until surfaceChanged()
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        initPreview(width, height);
        startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // no-op
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    }
};

Camera.PictureCallback PictureCallbackJpeg = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // no-op -- wait until surfaceChanged()
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        initPreview(width, height);
        startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // no-op
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] byteData, Camera camera) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 5;
        OutputStream bos = null;
        Bitmap m = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteData, 0, byteData.length, options);

        //m.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, bos);
        //Log.v("CAPTURED", ""+bos);
    }
};

private Camera getCamera(String getCamera) {
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
        if ((cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) && (getCamera == "front")) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("TEST", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
        else if ((cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) && (getCamera == "back")) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("TEST", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return cam;
}


}
```

EDIT:

I've editted the onPictureTaken to:

```
@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] byteData, Camera camera) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 5;
        OutputStream bos = null;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteData, 0, byteData.length, options);
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File file = new File(path, "TestFile.png");
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //m.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, bos);
        //Log.v("CAPTURED", ""+bos);
    }
```

Now there is a preview of the picture on the sd card and when I check it, the result is really weird. I've taken it in portrait modus.

[image: Portrait Picture taken]

Zoomed in:

[image: Portrait Picture taken zoomed in]